# Multiple "create"(s) in a single run oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have to create multiple tables,packages,sequences in a single file in oracle 10g.

This is how I am doing it.

```
create sequence "test1" start with 1 increment by 1 nomaxvalue
    /
    create sequence "test4" start with 1 increment by 1 nomaxvalue
```

Commencing error

```
ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
```

And when I do this

```
create sequence "test1" start with 1 increment by 1 nomaxvalue;

create sequence "test4" start with 1 increment by 1 nomaxvalue;
```

Error:

```
ORA-00911: invalid character
```

Please Help

Comment: Which version of Oracle database are you using? And by the way why do you need quotes for sequence names?

Comment: I can remove the quotes but that is not the problem i guess.. Version is 10.2.0.3

Comment: Where and how are you running these scripts - SQL Plus?  You shouldn't be getting those errors there.

Comment: You should remove the double quotes, otherwise you will end up with case-sensitive sequence names.

Comment: @KhurramZulfiqarAli With and without quotes, I am able to create multiple seqeunces in Oracle 10g.

Comment: Yes. and I want case sensitive in my DB. I am running it in Oracle Database Express Edition 10g (web interface)

Comment: @Polppan in a single run??

Comment: @KhurramZulfiqarAli Yes, single execution of statements, try running in SQL Plus.

Comment: @Polppan So you are saying  Web Interface is giving me errors and shell will not?

Comment: @KhurramZulfiqarAli That is what I could figure out, there are no other reasons for those errors.

Comment: ok. If I do agree with you then what can I do if I have to run in the web interface only?

Comment: @KhurramZulfiqarAli See [SQLDemo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/18a04/5), sequences are created, I do not have APEX web interfaces to test this.

Comment: Great! but Only a slight problem. "Its 11g R2" I am using 10g, 10.2.0.3 as I've mentioned before.

Comment: @KhurramZulfiqarAli Doesn't matter.

Comment: well 10.2.0.3 is giving errors and 11g is running the both create queries smoothly, so It does matter.

Comment: I had similar problems with some invisible characters embedded in the sql statements. You might want to try switching your environment (the terminal, the script file, etc.) to ascii and then retype the statements in sqlplus and see what happens.